# LINQ Bind in List

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, razor

i want to bind in list, how to do that, please see my code below

this below is my Controller

```
var transaction = await (from a in _context.Transaction group a by a.Nobukti into pg
                                     join b in _context.ChartAccount on pg.FirstOrDefault().Kodeakun
                                     equals b.Kodeakun
                                      select new Transaksi
                                      {   
                                          Nobukti = pg.FirstOrDefault().Nobukti,
                                          Tanggal = pg.FirstOrDefault().Tanggal,
                                          Keterangan = pg.FirstOrDefault().Keterangan,
                                          Trans = pg.ToList()
                                      }).ToListAsync();
 return View(transaction);
```

See my Trans = pg.ToList() in Controller, inside pg.ToList() there are Kodeakun, and i want bind to Kodeakun = a.Kodeakun + b.Kodeakun

This below is my Model

```
public class ChartAccount
    {
        [Key]
        public string Kodeakun { get; set; }
        public string Namaakun { get; set; }

        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C2}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public decimal Saldo { get; set; }
    }

public class Transaksi
    {   [Key]
        public int Iud { get; set; }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Nobukti { get; set; }
        public string Kodeakun { get; set; }
        public string Keterangan { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime Tanggal { get; set; }

        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C2}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = false)]
        public decimal Debit { get; set; }

        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C2}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = false)]
        public decimal Kredit { get; set; }

        public virtual List<Transaksi> Trans { get; set; }
    }
```

this below is my view

```
<table class="table">
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Nobukti) :
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Nobukti)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Keterangan) :
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Keterangan)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Tanggal) :
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Tanggal)
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>            
            @foreach (var transaksi in item.Trans)
            {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => transaksi.Kodeakun)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @if (transaksi.Debit == 0) { }
                    else
                    {
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => transaksi.Debit)
                    }
                </td>
                <td>
                    @if (transaksi.Kredit == 0) { }
                    else
                    {
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => transaksi.Kredit)
                    }
                </td>
            </tr>
    }

        </tbody>
    }
        </table>
```

sorry for my bad english, i use ASP Net Core 2.2

Comment: @RenéVogt sorry, i just update my description

Comment: You show us, how you retrieve that data and that looks okay, IMHO. But where do you like to use it? What is `View` and what technology is used by it to visualize things? Is it WPF, Winforms a WebPage or something else?

Comment: i use ASP NET CORE 2.2, I will update my view

Comment: Okay, we're making progress. ;-) You create a website on the server side holding all the data from the model. But what is the problem? Just from the I can't see any problems. You know how to access the data within the view (through the Model variable) and also how to access nested properties (by iterating on item.Trans). So, still don't know what your problem is.

Comment: my code sure is work, but my view is not what i want, See my Trans = pg.ToList() in Controller, inside pg.ToList() there are Kodeakun, and i want bind to Kodeakun = a.Kodeakun + b.Kodeakun, how do that?

Comment: @Oliver any suggest yet?

Comment: @RenéVogt any suggest yet?